# How to use multiple form action?

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I want to send 2 mails one to the admin and one to the normal person .For that i have two php scripts.
But the problem is i want to send both the mail in one click.
Can i use two form actions like sendmail.php and sendmail_client.php.
how do i do this ?

```
enter code here     <div class="clr"></div>
       <form action="sendmail.php" method="post" name="emailForm" id="emailForm">
    <input type="hidden" name="mode" value="send_eemail" />

            <div class="content_area">


                                <table class="form" width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="5">
                                    <tbody><tr><td colspan="2" class="error">* Required fields</td><div align="center" style="color:#FF0000; font-size:12px; font-weight:bold;" id="t"></div>
                                        <td class="error">&nbsp;</td></tr>
                                    <tr class="tr" style="padding:2px;">
                                        <td class="Career-body" style="width: 50%;">Name <span class="error">*</span></td>
                                        <td colspan="2">
                                        <input name="name" type="text" id="name" class="formText" size="40" required style="width: 267px"/></td>
                                    </tr>
```

```
</tbody></table> 

        </div></form>
```

Comment: You can add one hidden variable which value will be set according to click on different buttons, then on php you can decide on the basis of that value.

Comment: Put both the codes in a single file and then give it as action page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can append multiple email addresses like so:

```
$from = $_POST['email'];
$to = 'sampleemail@gmail.com';

$to .= "\n".$from;
$your_array = explode("\n", $to);
$imploded = implode(',', $your_array);
mail($imploded, $subject, $message, implode("\r\n", $headers));
```